# Troubleshooting Slurm cgroups Plugin on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, cgroups, slurm

I'm facing a [challenging issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77574925/2371987) with the [Slurm cgroups plugin](https://superuser.com/q/1818993/420688) on a system running Ubuntu 22.04. We're relatively new to Slurm and started using it for better resource management in complex computing tasks. However, we've hit a snag with the cgroups plugin, particularly on our Ubuntu 22.04 nodes.

Here's what we're experiencing:

- Initially tried the cgroups V2 plugin on our nodes (two with Ubuntu 22.04 and one with Ubuntu 18.04), which didn't work out.
- Switched to the cgroups V1 plugin, which allowed job execution on the Ubuntu 18.04 node but led to errors on the 22.04 nodes.
- The errors are related to `/sys/fs/cgroup` directories and include nodes going into `idle` and `drain` states after job attempts.

We've attempted kernel parameter modifications without success. I'm seeking insights on how to troubleshoot these cgroups plugin errors on Ubuntu 22.04.

As follows, are the logs where the errors start to appear:

```
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.479] [36.batch] error: unable to open '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset//tasks' for reading : No such file or directory
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.511] [36.batch] error: unable to mount cpuset cgroup namespace: Device or resource busy
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.511] [36.batch] error: unable to create cpuset cgroup namespace
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.511] [36.batch] error: unable to open '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices//tasks' for reading : No such file or directory
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.512] [36.batch] cgroup/v1: xcgroup_ns_create: cgroup namespace 'devices' is now mounted
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.514] [36.batch] error: common_cgroup_lock error
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.514] [36.batch] error: task_g_pre_setuid: task/cgroup: Unspecified error
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.514] [36.batch] error: Failed to invoke task plugins: one of task_p_pre_setuid functions returned error
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.515] [36.batch] error: called without a previous init. This shouldn't happen!
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.515] [36.batch] error: job_manager: exiting abnormally: Slurmd could not execve job
```

**Are there any known compatibility issues or specific diagnostic methods recommended for this environment?**

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: First, you should determine what version of `cgroups` is currently used on each of your machines so you can use the proper version of the required plugin: `mount | grep cgroup`.  Ubuntu 18 will likely be `cgroup` (v1) while the standard default on Ubuntu 22 should be `cgroup2`.  The errors you posted look to be from `cgroup`v1 which would not work if you are using `cgroup`v2.